# automatically editing a form textarea using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to edit a form textarea using js after a user has uploaded a text file. 
HTML has

```
<textarea name="program" class="code-editor form-control single" data-x-language="C" data-x-lines="8" data-optional="False" style="display: none;"></textarea>
```

The framework that I'm using has a js validator before posting the form to make sure the inputs are not empty

```
form.find('textarea,input[type="text"]').each(function()
{
    if($(this).attr('name') != undefined) //skip codemirror's internal textareas
    {
        if($(this).val() == "" && $(this).attr('data-optional') != "True")
            answered_to_all = false;
    }
});
```

I'm not 100% how the form is generated but I'm pretty it's using https://codemirror.net/

My code for automatically editing the textarea is

```
$('textarea.code-editor').val('bla bla')
```

3 things:

1. It's not working.
2. When typing manually using the keyboard the DOM element that gets updated is a `span` inside a `pre`. I've managed to automatically write on the DOM using a js to locate a `pre` element and `$(fileDisplayArea).text('bla bla')`. but's it's also not affecting the text area `val` thus failing the validation.
3. If I breakpoint in chrome and manually edit the `$(this).val()` inside the validation. Then it works.

Help pls.

Comment: Is it a textarea or its a customize tool? In the later case, it should have some API to interact

Comment: If it is the js editor from codemirror.net, read their docs on how to interact with the textarea? Like here: https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#api_content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, @Danmoreng
My mistake was addressing the DOM elements as plain elements instead of finding the relevant `CodeMirror` object and working with it like so

```
relevantCodeMirrorObject.getDoc().setValue(output)
```

how to find the `relevantCodeMirrorObject`? that is dependant on your code.